# Problema ao calcular e exibir o preço (R$) por pessoa

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou com um problema ao calcular e exibir o preço em R$ por pessoa em uma tabela.

No HTML abaixo, temos a quantidade de pessoas e uma tabela, nessa tabela temos o preço do plano e um campo em branco `<p class="pax-number"></p>` onde deverá exibir o preço por pessoa.

Me parecia simples até então, eu usei cada `<p class="preco-plano"></p>` para fazer um loop e transformar os valores em numero, calcular com a quantidade de pessoas e alterar o texto, porém não está sendo tão simples assim... Vejam o exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready( ()=> {
            //seleciona a quantidade de pessoas e transforma em um numero inteiro
            let paxNumber = parseInt(($(".pessoas .field-title").text()).split(" ")[0]);
            $('.preco-plano').each( ()=> {
                //seleciona o preço do plano e transforma em um numero inteiro
                let priceNumber = parseInt($(this).text().split('$')[1]);
                //calcula o preço por pessoa
                let pricePerPerson = priceNumber / paxNumber;
                //seleciona o campo onde deve ser exibido o valor por pessoa e escreve
                $(this).closest('p').find('.pax-number').html('R$' + pricePerPerson + 'por pessoa');
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pessoas">
        <span class="field-title">4 pessoas</span>
    </div>
    
    <table class="tabela-resultados">  
        <tr class="">
           <td class="bloco-preco" style="height: 180px;">
              <p class="nome-plano">Plano Tal</p>
              <span>
                 <p class="desconto">R$555,00</p>
                 <p class="preco-plano">R$316</p>
                 <p class="pax-number" style="color: green; font-size: 10px;"></p>
              </span>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="bloco-preco" style="height: 180px;">
                <p class="nome-plano">Plano XYZ</p>
                <span>
                    <p class="desconto">R$555,00</p>
                    <p class="preco-plano">R$420</p>
                    <p class="pax-number" style="color: green; font-size: 10px;"></p>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="bloco-preco" style="height: 180px;">
                <p class="nome-plano">Plano Cucurioso</p>
                <span>
                    <p class="desconto">R$555,00</p>
                    <p class="preco-plano">R$188</p>
                    <p class="pax-number" style="color: green; font-size: 10px;"></p>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
     </table>
     <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

acredito que o problema esteja quanto eu seleciono o valor e transformo em um numero inteiro `let paxNumber = parseInt(($(".pessoas .field-title").text()).split(" ")[0]);` pois ele não me da um numero, se eu tenho utilizar o seletor `$('.preco-plano')` ao invés de `$(this)` ele me retorna um NaN pq ele não pega apenas o valor daquele bloco, mas sim de todos os blocos da tabela. 
Tentei fazer algo parecido usando o `for` mas sem sucesso também.

Alguém conseguiria me dar uma luz, de o que estou fazendo de errado?

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problemas no código:

1) O `.each` do jQuery não aceita `$(this)` com *arrow function*:

Ou você usa `function()` com `$(this)` ou pega o segundo argumento (que é o elemento do laço) usando *arrow function*:

**Com arrow:**

```
$('.preco-plano').each( (i,e)=> {
    //seleciona o preço do plano e transforma em um numero inteiro
    let priceNumber = parseInt($(e).text().split('$')[1]);
    //calcula o preço por pessoa
    let pricePerPerson = priceNumber / paxNumber;
    //seleciona o campo onde deve ser exibido o valor por pessoa e escreve
    $(e).closest('span').find('.pax-number').html('R$' + pricePerPerson + 'por pessoa');
});
```

> Onde em `(i,e)`, o `i` é o índice do elemento e `e` o próprio
>   elemento.

**Com function:**

```
$('.preco-plano').each( function() {
    //seleciona o preço do plano e transforma em um numero inteiro
    let priceNumber = parseInt($(this).text().split('$')[1]);
    //calcula o preço por pessoa
    let pricePerPerson = priceNumber / paxNumber;
    //seleciona o campo onde deve ser exibido o valor por pessoa e escreve
    $(this).closest('span').find('.pax-number').html('R$' + pricePerPerson + 'por pessoa');
});
```

2) O `.closest('p')` está errado. o Correto seria `.closest('span')`, porque o `span` que é o pai do `p` de onde você selecionou a classe `.preco-plano`.

**Código (com arrow):**

```js
$(document).ready( ()=> {
   //seleciona a quantidade de pessoas e transforma em um numero inteiro
   let paxNumber = parseInt(($(".pessoas .field-title").text()).split(" ")[0]);
   $('.preco-plano').each( (i,e)=> {
       //seleciona o preço do plano e transforma em um numero inteiro
       let priceNumber = parseInt($(e).text().split('$')[1]);
       //calcula o preço por pessoa
       let pricePerPerson = priceNumber / paxNumber;
       //seleciona o campo onde deve ser exibido o valor por pessoa e escreve
       $(e).closest('span').find('.pax-number').html('R$' + pricePerPerson + 'por pessoa');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pessoas">
        <span class="field-title">4 pessoas</span>
    </div>
    
    <table class="tabela-resultados">  
        <tr class="">
           <td class="bloco-preco" style="height: 180px;">
              <p class="nome-plano">Plano Tal</p>
              <span>
                 <p class="desconto">R$555,00</p>
                 <p class="preco-plano">R$316</p>
                 <p class="pax-number" style="color: green; font-size: 10px;"></p>
              </span>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="bloco-preco" style="height: 180px;">
                <p class="nome-plano">Plano XYZ</p>
                <span>
                    <p class="desconto">R$555,00</p>
                    <p class="preco-plano">R$420</p>
                    <p class="pax-number" style="color: green; font-size: 10px;"></p>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td class="bloco-preco" style="height: 180px;">
                <p class="nome-plano">Plano Cucurioso</p>
                <span>
                    <p class="desconto">R$555,00</p>
                    <p class="preco-plano">R$188</p>
                    <p class="pax-number" style="color: green; font-size: 10px;"></p>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
     </table>
```

Comment: sinceramente! só tenho a agradecer! eu tinha chegado a ler sobre .each no w3School e fiz um teste usando o "element", porém com a sintaxe errada. Muito obrigado por me mostrar onde errei. Então sempre que eu usar o arrow function e precisar do .each, eu uso o "element" pra selecionar... e o closest, eu devo sempre selecionar o objeto pai correto? meu muito obrigado mesmo! tmj !

Comment: Isso mesmo. O arrow não referencia o $(this) na função.